# Vector Drawable not showing vertical line

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am creating drawable in xml using the vector. I am able to draw a rectangle using the path but when I am trying to draw a completely vertical or horizontal line its not showing.
Here is my code

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#c1ae1e"
        android:pathData="M0 0,H24,V24,H0,V0"/>

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:strokeColor="#4c4c4c"
        android:fillColor="#36352c"
        android:pathData="M12 0,L12 24"/>

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:strokeColor="#4c4c4c"
        android:fillColor="#36352c"
        android:pathData="M0 12,L24 12"/>

</vector>
```

And here is the preview output-
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try combining it into one path. I'm not sure why, but having a completely horizontal or vertical line with only two points will not render. Since I had to make a cross shape, I was able to get away with combining both the vertical or horizontal lines like so:

```
    <path
    android:strokeColor="#FF000000"
    android:strokeWidth="0.5"
    android:pathData="M14,0 l0,28 M0,14 l28,0"/>
```

This will also happen if you make an arc that calculates to be a straight like (not something most people would do, but I've seen it while changing arc values, and might be related as to why the lines do not show)

Give this a try:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="1"
        android:strokeColor="#c1ae1e"
        android:pathData="M0 0,H24,V24,H0,V0"/>

    <path
        android:strokeWidth="3"
        android:strokeColor="#4c4c4c"
        android:fillColor="#36352c"
        android:pathData="M12 0,L12 24 M0 12,L24 12"/>

</vector>
```

Comment: I want both lines with different colors bro!.:(

Comment: The only thing that seems to work there is to put 0.001 (or if you want to be absolutely sure, you can go even lower, no matter how many zeroes I put, it kept accepting it) in place of 0. It's definitely a bug, as using h,H,v and V doesn't work either. I haven't found anything that says it's part of how SVG is designed.

Comment: Better yet, turns out the issue may only be with the preview. I did some testing and it seems the horizontal and vertical lines appear just fine on device - but that does make the preview rather useless for these shapes.

Comment: Yeah this was not showing on the preview only, I tested on device and it worked perfectly, thanks man!